# how to delete specific cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2003

How do I delete specific cells in Microsoft Excel 2003?

I have excel 2003, windows xp. I want to select cells with specific text. I found [this](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/816-excel-select-cells-with-specific-text.html), but it is only for excel 2007 and up.

Example:

I have this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chJVb.png]

Then I just need to select all of the "p" like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cltKp.png]

Is this possible in excel 2003??

Comment: So based on the comment to ashokavarthanan's answer you dont just want to select them you want to delete the entire row for each?

Comment: @chancea I am sorry if I was not clear, but I want to select the specific cells and only delete the cells themselves. 

The issue isn't the deleting part because you can just do edit>delete. The issue is how do I select those cells?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288291

Comment: @chancea I know about the F+R function, but I need to have those cells get shifted up

Answer (score 0):

other way to use Notepad++ Easy To Edit.
1.Copy to Notepad++
2.Find "/tp/t" Note "/t" Mean "Tab"
3.Replace "/t?/t" Note "?" Mean What U replace?
Replace All
Copy And Paste to Excel.

Comment: It is critical for me to to do it in excel to keep formatting and it is also critical to shift row up after deletion